# Swift crashing when casting NSObject subclass to a non-objc protocol

Tags: swift, casting

I've spent some time figuring this out. This code crashes:

```
public protocol FourLeggedAnimal: AnyObject {

}

public class Animal: NSObject {

}

public class Dog: Animal, FourLeggedAnimal {

}


public class AnimalProperty<Kind: Animal>: NSObject {

    let animal: Kind

    public init(animal: Kind) {
        self.animal = animal
    }

}

public class FourLeggedAnimalProperty<Kind: Animal>: AnimalProperty<Kind>, NSTextFieldDelegate {

    public override init(animal: Kind) {
        /// Since we cannot express in Swift that the Kind should be an Animal
        /// subclass confirming to a particular protocol, we use a force-cast
        /// which is not a pretty solution, but there aren't any options.

        /// And this crashes.
        let fourLeggedAnimal = animal as! FourLeggedAnimal
        print(fourLeggedAnimal)

        super.init(animal: animal)
    }

}


let dog = Dog()
let property = FourLeggedAnimalProperty(animal: dog)
```

The code crashes in Swift's library's `getGenericPattern()` function when you attempt to cas the dog to the `FourLeggedAnimal` protocol in the intializer.

Notes:

- The correct way should be to declare the generics as `<Kind: Animal, FourLeggedAnimal>`, however, when you do so, you can't call the `init(animal:)` initializer with `Dog`, even though it's `Animal` and `FourLeggedAnimal`.
- The app crashes even when you use a soft-cast, i.e. it's not a wrong cast, it's actually a bug in Swift's runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to either declare the `FourLeggedAnimal` as `@objc`, or to make `Animal` **not** to inherit from `NSObject`.

Comment: Unfortunately, declaring as @objc is an imperfect solution if you need to work with swift specific features such as enums, and not inheriting from nsobject is sometimes impossible when dealing with many of the built in libraries. This bug/lack of feature makes protocol use, extremely frustrating.

Comment: Agreed. However, it took me some time to not make my code crash, so I've posted this semi-solution for anyone having the same issue. I've - of course - reported this issue to Apple as well... Well, since last August, I've filed over 70 bugs related to Xcode and Swift...